# on duplicate update multiple fields only on condition

Tags: php, mysql

looking for help with mysql/php

I'm using query to update table if user plays a quiz again.

The thing is, that I'm now using this query:  (KEY is set to email)
`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE correct = GREATEST(correct, $correct), time = LEAST(time, $time),`

But now I realised that it upgrades time even if the score is not greater.

Any tips to fix this? I want to update time only if score is greater or same.

Comment: Euhm, what has the title got to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE your_tablename.time = IF($correct >= your_tablename.correct, $time, your_tablename.time), your_tablename.correct = GREATEST(your_tablename.correct, $correct)
```